# Devexpress checked Combobox edit

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress

I have made Master-Detail form. Master part of form having customer basic information and in Detail part, When I select a Mobile having Faults like LCD Fault, Battery Fault.

> I use Devexpress CheckedComboBoxEdit to select multiple values
>   fetching the list of Mobile Faults from database e.g LCD Fault,
>   Speaker Fault, Battery Fault, Keypads Fault, Camera Fault.How can I
>   save selected Faults list to database along with mobile

Answer (score 1):

CheckedComboBoxEdit stores all the checked items' values (mapped via CheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.ValueMember) in property EditValue, separated with CheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.SeparatorChar.

So you can store all of your fault IDs (I presume they have values 1,2,3...) like this:

```
var faults = (myCheckedComboBoxEdit.EditValue ?? "").ToString().Split(myCheckedComboBoxEdit.Properties.SeparatorChar).Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: Which data type I have to select in SQL Server?

Comment: Depends on you database. I presumed you had a master-detail with ints.